# php: Read from local php file like a remote site

Tags: php, file, load, local

I'm wanting to have a page output the result of a local PHP file, but when trying to do it through `file_get_contents` I get an error:

```
file_get_contents(page.php?p=page1): failed to open stream: Result too large
```

I want to get the contents of page.php after sending the GET variable p, just like it would appear if you viewed page.php?p=page1 normally

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` is trying to read off the local filesystem the way you have that currently setup.

You need to give it a full URL like `http://yoursite.com/page.php?p=page1`.

Note that [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) has to be enabled for this to work.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Is there a good way I can get the "http://yoursite.com/" part dynamically? I'm writing this on localhost and plan on putting it on my server when it's up and running later.

Comment: Sure. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Or more specifically: `"http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/page.php?p=page1";`